# Async File Upload in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I know there are lots of examples and samples of `code` to upload the file `asynchronously`, but unfortunately no one is working for me.

I placed the update panel but `File Uploader` doesn't work in `update panel`.
I have 4 text fields and a `file uploader` on the page. I want to save all information and want to upload file without any `postback`.

I saw `AjaxFileUpload` control of ajax control toolkit but it uploads the file instantly when we select it. But i want to upload the file on click of the button.

Please let me know any one has solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax Control Toolkit you mentioned as an [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) that you can use. And yes, it can be hooked up to a button as demonstrated in the page I linked to. Please use it and then let us know specifically what problems you run into with it.

Comment: I saw this link as well. The upload button is with the ajax control.
I can't use separate button to upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same problem. All the examples I saw online did not work for me either. After stripping down the code, I figured I had to use `ToolKitScriptManager` and not the standard `asp:ScriptManager`. 

I have not use the the toolkit before so I don't know if this is a new requirement with the latest toolkit since all the older examples I read used the ScriptManager and said it is supposed to work fine.

Here is the code behind to save from a button click:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload afu = (AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload)sender;

    if (afu.HasFile)
    {
        Session["AsyncFileUploadImage"] = afu;
    }

}
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedFileError(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (Session["AsyncFileUploadImage"] != null)
    {
        this.AsyncFileUpload1 = (AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload)Session["AsyncFileUploadImage"];
        this.AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath,"images", "uploads", this.AsyncFileUpload1.FileName)); //make sure to save in directory with write permissions
        this.lblStatus.Text = "You uploaded " + AsyncFileUpload1.FileName;
    }
    else
    {
      ...
    }


}
```